# How to Extend AutoComplPop filename Completion?

Tags: vim, autocomplete, vim-plugin

Based on AutoComplPop documentation it uses text before the cursor to selects the completion method. for example if the text before cursor is `a filename character + a path separator + 0 or more filename character` the filename completion is used, i. e. `<c-x><c-f>` is feeded.
What if we want to extend this behaviour to when text before the cursor is for example `href="` or `src="`?

I think AutoComplPop uses the following function to match text before the cursor and triggers filename completion :

```
function acp#meetsForFile(context)
  if g:acp_behaviorFileLength < 0
    return 0
  endif
  if has('win32') || has('win64')
    let separator = '[/\\]'
  else
    let separator = '\/'
  endif
  if a:context !~ '\f' . separator . '\f\{' . g:acp_behaviorFileLength . ',}$'
    return 0
  endif
  return a:context !~ '[*/\\][/\\]\f*$\|[^[:print:]]\f*$'
endfunction
```

Comment: One idea is to consider `"` as a part of filename you can add it like `:set fname+=34`. From now onwards, filename completion might work. Other way is to do something in plugin. Let's go with first one :)

Comment: @SibiCoder,  I have already doing that with adding `if a:context =~ '\%\(href\|src\|action\)="$' | return 1 | endif` to above code for **html** files for example; and its working fine ;)

Comment: You can add it as a proper answer. It might help others in tr future :)